# a.e. -convergence implies $L^p-$convergence or no?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples, almost-everywhere

Is the vice versa in the corollary below true? If not, could you give me a counterexample?[image]

Thank you so much.

Comment: There are lots of examples (even using Riemann integrable functions) of (nonnegative) $f_n$ that converge to $0$ pointwise but all have $\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx = 1$.

Comment: The converse doesn't make logical sense without rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_{n}\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by

$$
\begin{aligned}
f_{n}(x):=
\begin{cases}
1&\text{ if } x\in[n,n+1]\\
0& \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$

Then, for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$, we have that $f_{n}(x)$ is eventually $0$. Thus, $f_{n}\to 0 $ pointwise. But, $\|f_{n}\|_{p}=1$ for all $n$. Thus, $f_{n}$ does not converge to $0$ in $L^{p}$.